# Php compare hours H:i as string

Tags: php, time

What do you think about this solution.

for example:

```
 $firstHour = '08:30';
 $secondHour = '12:30';
 $test = $firstHour >= $secondHour; // will be false
 $test2 = $secondHour >= $firstHour; //will be true
```

Is that solution has any weakness?

Comment: is it always in same date ? and is it 24 or 12 hrs format ?

Comment: Yes in same date, 24 hrs format

Comment: @John Conde why duplicate? Other answers dont have above solution.

Comment: @Bart1 - The answers in the duplicate show you how to use `strtotime()`, and more, to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @John Conde I know how to use strtotime, i asked about weakness using string compare.

Comment: If everyone is saying to use it, why would you think it has a weakness?

Comment: Less code, without using function created in php 5.0

Comment: @JohnConde I changed title so now it is not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using convert time to [**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$firstHour = strtotime('08:30');
$secondHour = strtotime('12:30');

$test = $firstHour >= $secondHour; 
$test2 = $secondHour >= $firstHour;
```

Comment: Thanks but what do you think about above solution, if u compare hours in same day.

Comment: Is faster than strotime.